# Enabling System.Net.Http within VS 2012 Project

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-config, drools

I'm fairly new to JSON development and just getting started is a major task with very little in the way of solutions via Google.

I can't get anywhere without adding system.net.http as part of my project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;
```

objects like var, HttpWebClient, KeyValuePair throw up an error during compile. Here's what I tried:

- Reinstalled .NET 4.0
- Reinstalled .NET 4.5
- Repackaged library via. NuGet
- Referenced system.net

No luck. I've even tried referencing the the class in web.config

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

and again in..

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

An error is thrown on "assemblies"

I'm at my wits end. What am I not referencing or doing wrong where System.Net.Http cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help system reveals that the System.Net.Http namespace is defined in System.Net.Http.dll which as you say is not listed. A quick search of my own filesystem reveals copies

- In the GAC
- In the framework folders for both 32 and 64 bit

On my system those paths are

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll is on the same paths.

Comment: I could slap myself. Got used to easily referencing the library directly that I forgot to map it directly. Worked like a charm. However HttpWebClient, FormURLEncodedContent, StreamReader, and KeyValuePair (although are part of the heirachy) throw an error: "Expected class or..."

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 4.5 System.Net.Http is in it's own assembly, you have to go to "Add References" (right click on the project) and select it.

See the MSDN page for HttpClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

> Assembly:  System.Net.Http (in System.Net.Http.dll)

Comment: I opened Add Reference, and added System.Net under the .NET tab. The Add Reference form does mention that it is filtered to .NET Framework 4. Could this be a problem? I'm not sure if System.Net.Http is a .NET 4.5 library. I check GAC_MSIL and the system.net.http assembly does exist. I am wondering how to reference it.

Comment: Make sure your Project is set up as a .NET 4.5 Framework target: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

C# is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Wow, they were not kidding about response time with stackoverflow.. Sorry I digress. Yes I added ..using System.Net.Http; the autofinder does not list Http {} as an option, indicating that for some reason it is not loaded